# VB.NET equivalent for the C# 7 is operator declaration pattern

Tags: vb.net, casting, variable-declaration, c#-7.0

Is there a VB.NET equivalent to the [C# 7 is operator declaration pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns)? *Note in particular the `bmp` in the following code sample:*

```
public void MyMethod(Object obj)
{
    if (obj is Bitmap bmp)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or the short pattern matching syntax with `is` is exclusive to C#?

**EDIT:**

I already know these syntaxes:

```
    If TypeOf obj Is Bitmap Then
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = obj
        ' ...
    End If
```

or

```
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = TryCast(obj, Bitmap)
    If bmp IsNot Nothing Then
        ' ...
    End If
```

What I want to know is whether there is something even shorter, like [that new C#7 is operator declaration pattern...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't asked clearly from begginning. Please see edit.

Comment: I think there is no. The team of vb.net [chose not to run after the incessant improvements of C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2017/02/01/digging-deeper-into-the-visual-basic-language-strategy/).

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/124 https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/172

Comment: This trick isn't the cast. The trick is the variable declaration in the same line of code.

Comment: There are now a few related open proposals on the vblang Github repo; see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/337) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/367) among others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, no. If you want to implement this, you'll have to use some of the longer formats you already mention in your question.

The C# and VB languages don't always have equivalent features.

Answer (score -1):

Use a one line if

```
If obj is bitmap Then Dim bmp = obj
```

or use an in-line if  (this is the if function)

```
Dim bmp = If(obj is bitmap, obj, Nothing)
```

Not quite pattern-matching per se, but is does the same thing.

Couldn't you do it this way in C#:

```
var bmp = obj is bitmap ? obj : nothing;
```

Comment: As far as my testing goes, this would miss object typing and return Object type.

Comment: `obj is bitmap` is illegal.

Comment: Don't do any of these. Use the standard (and already mentioned) `Dim bmp As Bitmap = TryCast(obj, Bitmap)`. If `Option Strict` is ON and `Option Infer` is OFF, then `Dim` acts like c#'s `var, so can shorten this to `Dim bmp = TryCast(obj, Bitmap)`.